# Como exibir os metadados dos arquivos shape e raster no PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Boa tarde! Primeiramente, essa é a primeira postagem que faço no fórum e sou iniciante no quesito PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Estou trabalhando em um projeto que envolve banco de dados espacializados no qual eu preciso encontrar a melhor forma de exibir no PostgreSQL os metadados dos meus arquivos shapes e rasters, que estão sendo editados e criados. Após muita pesquisa, não encontrei algo que realmente me ajudasse... Como os metadados ficam alojados no arquivo xml do shape, eles não vão para o PostgreSQL, e era exatamente isso que eu queria, exibí-los. A única coisa que encontrei nessa linha seria criar uma tabela com os metadados que quero exibir e vinculá-la às tabelas dos meus produtos. Realmente não existe uma possibilidade de exibir essas informações no Banco de Dados sem ser criando uma tabela?
Enfim... Não sei se fui muito claro mas, basicamente, o que eu preciso é exibir os metadados dos meus arquivos no PostgreSQL.
Alguma ideia?

Abraço!

Henrique

Answer (score 0):

Se você puder ler o arquivo XML antes de salvar dados na sua tabela e sua tabela teria um campo tipo 'text' para armazenar o metadado do arquivo, isto serviria?

Dê uma olhada no link da [ajuda do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) e veja se te serve.